# VSCode remove command from command palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing an extension in VSCode and I register a command via registerCommand(...) function.   Is there a way to remove
one command from the palette commands programmatically without removing
the extension?

Comment: you can specify the `when` to false in the command palette menu, see the menu doc page

Comment: If it's a built-in command or a command from another extension - no.

Comment: If you want to control a command that you've added for your extension - check out the `when` parameter: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#controlling-when-a-command-shows-up-in-the-command-palette

Comment: Is this command something you want in the Command Palette sometimes and other times not?  If so, see the above comments.  If you want to register the command but never show it in the Command Palette, just don't put it in the `package.json`.